# CursorWindow: Failed to read row 1411, column 3 from a CursorWindow which has 1411 rows, 4 columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm reading a db with 32000 entries and update them like this:

```
public void updateTable(@NotNull String title) {                                                                                                                                                                          
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<span id=\"v(.+?)\" class=\"v\">.+?</span>");                                          

    SQLiteDatabase database = dbwraper.getDatabase();                                                                          

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher("");                                                                                          
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();                                                                               
    String[] args = new String[]{""};                                                                                         
    String selection = "_Id=?";                                                                                      

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();                                                                           
    try (SQLiteCursor cursor = (SQLiteCursor) database.query(TABLE_NAME,                                        
            new String[]{"_Id", "Label", "Content", "AdjustmentInfo"}, null, null, null, null, "_Id ASC")) {

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            byte[] info = cursor.getBlob(3);
            args[0] = cursor.getString(0);
            if (info == null) {
                database.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, args);
                continue;
            }

            String content = process(dbwraper.getDeobfuscator(), cursor.getBlob(2));
            m.reset(content);
            m.matches();

            log.e("m.group(1) = " + m.group(1));
            String[] ids = m.group(1).split("-");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(ids[0]) * 1000000 + Integer.parseInt(ids[1]) * 1000 + Integer.parseInt(ids[2]);

            map.put(args[0], id);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());                                                                                                                   
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                                                                   
        e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                         

    database.beginTransaction();                                                                                              

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {                                                                                         
        args[0] = key;                                                                                                        
        values.clear();                                                                                                       
        values.put("_Id", map.get(key));                                                                             
        database.update(TABLE_NAME, values, selection, args);                                                                
    }                                                                                                                         

    database.setTransactionSuccessful();                                                                                      
    database.endTransaction();                                                                                                 
}
```

The problem araises when the cursor reads the last entry. I get this error:

```
CursorWindow: Failed to read row 1411, column 3 from a CursorWindow which has 1411 rows, 4 columns.
```

I can't seem to see the problem. Is it a memory allocation issue? Or is my db malformed?

Comment: use `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {...`, not `do {...} while(...)` and of course remove `cursor.moveToFirst();`

Comment: isn't it the same thing?

Comment: **NO**, it's actually not. It's all about **WHEN** the `moveToNext()` method is executed.

Comment: I get the same error. And I think that you are wrong. If I move to first and then DO while moveToNext() is equvalent to while moveToNext().

Comment: Rolled back, because you changed the original code. Which makes the comments and the answer/s useless.

Comment: ok so what does `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor` show? call it before your `while` loop

Comment: Ok, just a sec.

Comment: and no, `while (...)` is not the same as `do {...`, first it is more natural, less code, and what if the result set is empty?

Comment: True! here is the dump https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2vkg1nEXylkdzdxdjU0eVh6U2M

Comment: ok then use `while (cursor.moveToNext()) {...` in the loop body just call `cursor.getString(0)` after the loop call `Log.d` with the value of `cursor.getPosition` and compare it to `cursor.getCount`, if its ok add `cursor.getBlob(3)` to the loop body and run your code again

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly.

Comment: so what was wrong?

Comment: I first deleted all the raws that had null values in AdjustmentInfo column, and then do the query as @ModularSynth suggested  database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE AdjustmentInfo IS NULL");

Comment: yep, i missed you are deleting the rows in the loop...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @pskink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your loop from:

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
       [...]
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

to

```
    // IMPORTANT: REMOVE THIS LINE!! cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext() {
       [...]
    }
```

Comment: Did you remove the `cursor.moveToFirst();` line?

Comment: Yes I did. :D :D

Comment: Then it **has to** work. When you retrieve the cursor, you at index **-1**. Then with the first `moveToNext()` you get to the first row (index = **0**). And you move on till the last row.

Comment: I wish that for 4 hours.

Comment: Now, as with arrays, if you're going to delete something, I'd start from the last element and come up, instead of doing the opposite. Furthermore... why are you deleting a table ROW BY ROW?! Delete it all at once - or delete all the specific rows which match a particular condition, also all at once.